# Variable doesn't work in else

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, if-statement

I have this code for chat, but there's a problem with the `$profile_pic` variable (which contains the path to a profile pic): when I `echo` its value before the `if` statement, it works; or if I put it in the `if` branch, it also works; but if I put it in the `else` branch, then it doesn't work.

```
<?php
require('../../includes/db.php');

$result_msg = $link->query("SELECT  * FROM chat ORDER BY msg_id");
while($row_msg = $result_msg->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sender = $row_msg['sender'];
    $qry = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = '".$sender."'");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($qry, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $profile_pic = $data["profile_pic"];
    $message = $row_msg["message"];
    if($sender == $_SESSION['admin_auth'] or $_SESSION['user_auth']){
      echo '<div class="messageme"><div class="messagemebody">' . $row_msg["message"]. '</div><br></div>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<div class="messageyou"><img src="'.$profile_pic.'" alt="profile_pic" class="profile_pic_chat"><div class="messageyoubody">'.$message.'</div><br></div>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: `if($sender == $_SESSION['admin_auth'] or $_SESSION['user_auth'])` doesn't do what you think it does.  You probably meant `if($sender == $_SESSION['admin_auth'] or $sender == $_SESSION['user_auth'])`?

Comment: It is because the pointer is not entering in else condition. If the `if` condition doesn't satisfies then it will go in `else` automatically

Comment: start session at the top

Comment: @eggyal Yes, i checked and `src` is empty

Comment: @PardeepPathania Nothing about `session`, because when `echo` it before `if` statement it `echo` it's path

Comment: try to replace 
if($sender == $_SESSION['admin_auth'] or $_SESSION['user_auth']){

with  
if($sender == $_SESSION['admin_auth'] || isset($_SESSION['user_auth'])){

Answer (score 0):

If the $message variable in the else is working you should look into the asset pipeline as it could be a path issue.

Comment: Also if that doesnt work try using an **else if** instead of an **else** and make a condition when the pointer should enter the **else if**

Comment: try exchanging the echo conditions in the if and else to make sure the problem is not in the echo statement

Comment: Hmm. if i exchanged conditions it worked and showed profile pictures but for messages from me and i wanted to show profile pictures to messages from others

Comment: add another if and make sure the condition is such that one doesn't run when the other runs.